# Is it possible to create a better version of this primelist generator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have struggled a bit with this one. I need to reduce the time that this programm needs to find all the primes in a certain range. 
This is what I came up with thus far.

```
def generatePrimeList(lo=2, up=800):
print "generatePrimeList", lo, up
primeList = []
for x in range (lo, up):
    Prime = True
    for y in range(lo, int(math.sqrt(x))):
        if x % y == 0:
            Prime = False
            break
    if Prime:
        primeList.append (x)
return primeList
```

Comment: look for "sieve of erathosthenes"... not sure if you can adjust to the low range, but it's very good to generate all primes up to n. at http://codereview.stackexchange.com they have a ton of examples.

Comment: This question pertains more towards Algo than its implementation.

Comment: read here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174083/implementation-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-python